# How to stop java method execution after throwing exception inside of 'inner' method?

Tags: java, exception

I wrote an example which depicts my issue.
I have a simple exception:

```java
public class TryToSpeakException extends RuntimeException {

    public TryToSpeakException(String message) {
        super(message);
    }
}
```

Then I have a chain of methods that invoke each other one by one:

```java
public class TryToSpeak {

    public static void speakToPerson1() {
        throw new TryToSpeakException("Person 1 don't wanna speak to anyone.");
    }

    public static void speakToPerson2() {
        try {
            speakToPerson1();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println("speakToPerson2 caused exception");
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public static void speakToPerson3() {
        try {
            speakToPerson2();

        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println("speakToPerson3 caused exception");
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    static void keepSilentToPerson() {
        System.out.println("Keeping silent to person 1");
    }

    public static void communicate() {
        try {
            speakToPerson3();

            keepSilentToPerson(); // Why it reaches this part?
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println("Communication exception.");
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        communicate();
    }
}
```

The method from the very 'bottom' throws an exception. In method `communicate()` after invocation of method `speakToPerson3()` the execution keeps going.
What i need - is to Stop execution, so that invocation of method `keepSilentToPerson()` is never reached and gives me the message `"Communication exception."`.

This is what i get in console now:

```
speakToPerson2 caused exception
exceptions.TryToSpeakException: Person 1 don't wanna speak to anyone.
    at exceptions.TryToSpeak.speakToPerson1(TryToSpeak.java:7)
    at exceptions.TryToSpeak.speakToPerson2(TryToSpeak.java:12)
    at exceptions.TryToSpeak.speakToPerson3(TryToSpeak.java:22)
    at exceptions.TryToSpeak.communicate(TryToSpeak.java:36)
    at exceptions.TryToSpeak.main(TryToSpeak.java:46)
Keeping silent to person 1
```

But if i call `speakToPerson2()` from my Main method like this:

```
public static void speakToPerson1() {
    throw new TryToSpeakException("Person 1 don't wanna speak to anyone.");
}

public static void speakToPerson2() {
    try {
        speakToPerson1();

        keepSilentToPerson();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.out.println("speakToPerson2 caused exception");
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

static void keepSilentToPerson() {
    System.out.println("Keeping silent to person 1");
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    speakToPerson2();
}
```

I get an obvious result:

```
    speakToPerson2 caused exception
    exceptions.TryToSpeakException: Person 1 don't wanna speak to anyone.
    at exceptions.TryToSpeak.speakToPerson1(TryToSpeak.java:7)
    at exceptions.TryToSpeak.speakToPerson2(TryToSpeak.java:12)
    at exceptions.TryToSpeak.main(TryToSpeak.java:26)
```

`keepSilentToPerson()` is not reached.

What am i doing wrong?

Comment: speakToPerson3 catch all the exceptions, then it's obvious that your communicate method will run without any error

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`speakToPerson2()` is catching the Exception, but you want `communicate()` to catch it too. Essentially, `speakToPerson2()` is suppressing the exception, so no other method sees it.

What you need to do is rethrow it (in both `speakToPerson2()` and `speakToPerson3()`). This is known as *propagating* an exception.

I.e.:

```
public static void speakToPerson2() {
    try {
      speakToPerson1();
    } catch (Exception e) {
      System.out.println("speakToPerson2 caused exception");
      e.printStackTrace();
      throw e;
    }
  }

  public static void speakToPerson3() {
    try {
      speakToPerson2();

    } catch (Exception e) {
      System.out.println("speakToPerson3 caused exception");
      e.printStackTrace();
      throw e;
    }
  }
```

Comment: Thank you guys, this is exactly what i need! I will play around with it.

Answer (score 2):

You need to understand exactly how `try-catch` work. If any method in the try-catch throws an exception (one that extends/or is Exception in your example), the body of the try-catch will be interrupted to go into the `catch` clause.

In your case, the method `speakToPerson1` will throw a `TryToSpeakException`. This exception will be forwarded one step above in the method call stack, the method `speakToPerson2` in your case. Since the call to `speakToPerson1` is surrounded with a `try-catch`, the `catch` clause is invoked and `System.out.println("speakToPerson2 caused exception");` is executed. Now, the `try` clause encloses two methods calls, namely `speakToPerson1` and `keepSilentToPerson`. However, since the first method throw the exception, the second is never reached and therefore `keepSilentToPerson()` will never by called.

Finally, think about the catching of exceptions. If you catch an exception, you are saying that you are going to handle it, by recovering or rethrowing it. If you handle it without rethrowing it, it won't be forwarded to the upper level of your call stack. Beware of this technicality

Answer (score 0):

You can throw the exception after catching it `speakTo*` methods. This will stop execution of code in methods calling `speakTo*` and their catch block will be executed.

```java
       catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println("speakToPerson2 caused exception");
            e.printStackTrace();
            throw e;
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to propagate your Exceptions to the main class to completely stop the execution of a program.

In the case 1: All your exception will be handled by `speakToPerson2` function.

In the case 2: Your exception occurs at the function call of `speakToPerson1`, so the rest of your code will not execute.

So, inorder to stop the program from running you just have to propagate the exception, using `throw` keyword, in the catch block of your exception.